# implementing an SSO login

Tags: java, single-sign-on, servlet-filters, servlet-listeners

Im implemeting an SSO login feature for an application where the SSO credentials from the host site are sent in the request body along with my applications URL which i need to process when the index.jsp for my page is launched.
The approach I'm trying is to store these SSO credentials (as a value object) in the Servlet context like this:
context.setAttribute("ssoCredentials", ssoLoginVO);

using a Servlet filter , And later retrieve it by calling
servletContext.getAttribute("ssoCredentials")

from a PhaseListener on the login page. However trying to get the attribute doesn't work, although I do see other attributes when printing the list of attribute names.

Is there a flaw in this approach or am i not using the right methods to fecth what i need? Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: What is your problem : getting attribute from servlet context or using servlet context for storing credentials (which is *uncommon*) ?

Comment: Are you using Kerberos?

Comment: Well the problem is getting the attribute from the context. And no i'm not using Kerberos, afaik it's a homegrown SSO implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by setting the value inside the session itself. And later retreiving it inside the bean class. I had to however take care of preventing the session from getting invalidated in this case (when the SSO login was used).